# Custom model binder to map null input value to null for nullable value types

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-binding, nullable

In my web service I have several input models that take in `Nullable<TValue>` types like `int?` and `bool?`.

If I send the JSON `{ myNullabool: null }` for an input model with property `bool? MyNullabool` the default model binder maps `null` to `false` rather than `null`.

In general, it seems to map a null input to `default(TValue)` rather than `null`.

I've been able to deal with this in most cases by checking if a given property is equal to the default value, but of course for `bool?` this is not a possibility as `false` is often meaningful. And I could create my own reference type for `bool` so that the default value would be `null` but this seems silly.

So, I am wondering how I might go about either 1) configuring the default model binder to map `null` `Nullable`s to `null`, or 2) creating a custom model binder specifically to handle only `Nullable`s and deferring to the default binder for all other types

And out of curiosity, is there a good reason that Microsoft chose to implement the default model binder in this counterintuitive way? It seems like people would only choose to use a `Nullable` type if they felt that null values were possible and meaningful.

Comment: What version of MVC are you using? I just tried your example with MVC 5 and it seems to work correctly - if i pass "{Test: null}" to controller with model which contains "public bool? Test { get; set; }" then in my controller i get "null" for "Test" property.

Comment: I used web api Post method for testing.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets I am using MVC5 as well - but try doing the same thing with `bool?` as a property in a model you are posting, ie `BoolWrapper` containing property `public bool? Test` and then controller action `public string TestAction(BoolWrapper model)`

Comment: Maybe you have some other model binder which breaks this functionality? Try to create empty web application and test it.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets I'll double-check but I don't think so.